# Number repeat events

Tags: civievent

We have set it up so we use a drupal form to register for events. 
We have repeating events, and the form lets you sign up for all of them in one go.

When we go to set up the events form, our dropdown just shows the title of the event ie "after school football" six times. this is confusing as we may not select all of these or select one more than once.
I am looking for some way to have it so the repeating events are numbered, or have their dates beside them.

Here is a picture to try and illustrate what I am meaning:

[image]

Comment: are the repeating events numbered in civicrm itself?

Comment: No they are not, but I'd like them to be, any ideas? I am struggling to find where I can make this change and have little php experience to try and figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is no code that I know off. It's certainly possible we can add an id (or date or something) to the Event listing in the admin-config page. End-user org can become an official Webform CiviCRM sponsor as of $300; send me a direct message if you're interested in learning more.

I would also be happy to review a PR if you (and/or your developer) would like to submit one - I'm a co-maintainer on https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm